# Handling Google Play Service Update Message

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using googleservices in my application, the version 8.3. However when I downloaded my app on my old device (LG II Optimus), it showed me the following message

> This app won't run unless you update Google Play
>   Services

I accepted and updated google services and then I could able to use my application. However I wonder what if user is not willing to update his current google play services in his device? How should I handle it? What is the recommended approach to handle?

What is the lowest version of google play services recommended or does anybody knows what is the Facebook google play service version or how could I find it?

Comment: If you are not using newer APIs, you can try lowering the google service version in your application a little bit. I'm using something like 7.8.

Comment: But how do I know percentage of google play services on the current market? By knowing that, then I will try to eliminate some percentage and focus on majority. For example for iOS, I know I should focus only on iOS8 and iOS 9 because they are 90 percent of the market, I should ignore the rest. For Android, I do not want to ignore the majority by mistake if there is still huge percentage in the google play services 6 or 7. I am hope I explain the situation in detail. Do you know Facebook google play services version?

Comment: not every app is integrating google play services, for example facebook might not. Moreover, upgrading the device OS is something a user might not want to do, but upgrading the google play services is not a big deal. My suggestion is to use GPS 7.8 or such and don't worry about it. Users with a lower version will just upgrade. GPS distribution among users is not a public information.

Comment: I wonder some people are not willing to upgrade their current services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How should I handle it?

Your app should simply refuse to start if no required Google Play Services (GPS from now on) is present, as your code may be using stuff not present in currently installed, outdated, version of GPS, which in most cases would result in app crashing.

What causes the upgrade dialog is version mismatch between Google Play Services installed on device and version of GPS you build your app against. This version is stored in your Manifest file:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

My personal experience tells it's right approach to resist from upgrading GPS as soon as upgrade shows up in SDK Manager, and (unless you sure you want this) it's wise to resist for at least couple of weeks (or perhaps even completely avoid unless you need new features etc).

Major problem you can face with rushed upgrade is bad user experience. If you have your app built with new GPS SDK and released as soon as you see new GPS SDK is released by Google, then your users will be offered upgrade in Play Store (or auto upgraded). But then some of them (sometimes "some" is high percentage) may face problems not being able to launch your updated app because there's still no Google Play Service upgrade available for them (due to distribution, region, whatever). So each start would tell "Hej, upgrade or GTFO". But there's no upgrade. Guess who will be punished by user with one star ratings...

> What is the lowest version of google play services recommended or does anybody knows what is the Facebook google play service version or how could I find it?

Same as with your app, you can get this from app's Manifest file if you really need to know.

Comment: But how do I know percentage of google play services on the current market? By knowing that, then I will try to eliminate some percentage and focus on majority. For example for iOS, I know I should focus only on iOS8 and iOS 9 because they are 90 percent of the market, I know I should ignore the lower operating systems. For Android, I do not want to ignore if there is still huge percentage in the google play services 6 or 7. I am hope I explain the situation in detail.

Comment: thanks for the detail explanation. I wonder what GPS version you recommend me to use in my app? I have upvoted and marked your answer.

Comment: Use recent GPS, with 2-3 weeks of delay. That should be safe approach.

Comment: The recent version of GPS is 8.4.89 which has been released a couple of weeks ago (December 5, 2015). But my concern is what if user is not willing to update installed GPS on his device which is lower than 8.4.89?

Comment: Then I'd say it is his decision with all the consequences. You cannot do much about so I'd not really bother too much

Comment: by doing so, do not you believe I may lose one of my potential customer for my app?

Comment: Judge yourself, but mind you cannot please everyone.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcin.