# Is there any way to customize message "This app won't run unless you update Google Play services" or Skip the message by user choice

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

We have implemented, GCM ( Google Cloud Messaging ) for sending notifications to App.

If the Google Play Service in a particular device, is not the latest as required, the app display the above message on start of App. We have implemented the same in SplashScreen.java activity in our app. So it is visible for few seconds to the user on top of the splash screen. Splash activity does some other job, so it stays visible for approx 10 to 30 seconds.

Currently we are using "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0" as dependencies.

We have also tried creation of "GoogleCloudMessaging gcm" variable instance inside the scope of a function, which we can call or skip, if required.

But if we skip the creation of "GoogleCloudMessaging" variable, still we are finding the message on start of app.

There are devices, where user does not have enough space to update the "Google Play Service", so to stop showing the user this message everytime, is there any way to skip or change this alert message on start of app?

The link [Handling Google Play Service Update Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858366/handling-google-play-service-update-message) is possibly the nearest question, but still we do not have required answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This may be also relevant: [How to make google play games optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210370/how-to-make-google-play-games-optional)

> You say that:
>
> > But if we skip the creation of "GoogleCloudMessaging" variable, still we are finding the message on start of app.
>
> However you should not only skip creation but also **avoid** class which  imports anything from GooglePlayServices